# Bash LeftPad String with spaces inside variable

Tags: linux, bash

I wanted something like this:

```
  CUSTOMERNAME="THIS IS A TEST"
  printf "| %-30s " $CUSTOMERNAME
```

But the problem is, that the value **CUSTOMERNAME** has some space. The output looks likes this:

```
 | THIS                           | IS                             | A                              | TEST
```

But I wanted something like this

```
 | THIS IS A TEST                |
```

What can I do? Any ideas?

Thanks,
Hauke

Comment: possible duplicate of [I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To prevent word expansion, double quote the variable:

```
printf "| %-30s " "$CUSTOMERNAME"
```

Comment: And add an echo after the variable to get a newline, `printf "| %-30s " "$CUSTOMERNAME"; echo`.

Comment: @Hauke Basically **always** quote your variables.